# How to send email from any one email using Microsoft Graph

Tags: asp.net-core, email, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am using microsoft graph to send email. This email I want to send from any email that exists in the Active directory.
I already have get the permission on Mail.Send and have admin consent on Azure.So all set on the Azure level for access and permission.

Now when come to code. I have searched for but I am not able to figure out how to call the Microsoft graph api to send the email. Below is the code that I have been finding when I am doing search.  How I can replace the below code to send the email to anyone from anyone in Azure AD to anyone in Azure AD. Also the code for send email 'Send AS'.

```
  await graphClient.Me.Messages
              .Request()
                .AddAsync(message);
```

Comment: Any update or further concerns on this case sir?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The intention is the signed in user will not send email from his email
> address, the email notification will be asthmatically sent by someone
> else name to someone.

Then I think you wanna provide a sending email to your users, users can choose who received the email, but all the email should be sent be a specific account, such as `admin@xxx.onmicrosoft.com`, then you should know something about the sending email api.

As @user2250152 mentioned, `await graphClient.Users["userId"]`, here the `userId` means who send the email, as your requirement is sending all emails from one specific email address, it should hardcode as `admin@xxx.onmicrosoft.com`.

The next is how to send the email, calling ms graph api should offer an access token, as your requirement is sending email by the application but not every user, so I'm afraid the client credential flow is a better choice so that when the scenario comes to `sending email from several specific email addresses`, you don't need to change the flow then. Now you need to require your tenant admin to add `Mail.Send Application` api permission in azure ad to use this kind of flow.

[image]

And here's the code:

```
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;
var mesg = new Message
{
    Subject = "Meet for lunch?",
    Body = new ItemBody
    {
        ContentType = BodyType.Text,
        Content = "The new cafeteria is open."
    },
    ToRecipients = new List<Recipient>
    {
        new Recipient
        {
            EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
            {
                //who will receive the email
                Address = "xxx@gmail.com"
            }
        }
    },
    Attachments = new MessageAttachmentsCollectionPage()
};

var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
var tenantId = "your_tenant_name.onmicrosoft.com";
var clientId = "azure_ad_app_client_id";
var clientSecret = "client_secret_for_the_azuread_app";
var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
    tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
await graphClient.Users["user_id_which_you_wanna_used_for_sending_email"].SendMail(mesg, false).Request().PostAsync();
```

Comment: followed the same but it's not working . Mail was sending only if i use AD account but for gmail account mail not sending. Getting Exception of type 'Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors.ODataError' was thrown.'

Comment: `mail was sending only if i use AD account but for gmail account mail not sending` --> we are using ms graph api to send the email so we should use the microsoft account in your tenant which account should like `xx@tenantname.onmicrosoft.com`. Gmail account is not provided by Ms. If you have your gmail account to register into your tenant which makes you be able to use gmail account to sign in Azure AD, then you should have a corresponding account like `xx_gmail.com#EXT#@tenantname.onmicrosoft.com` and this is the account you should use.

Comment: by the way, you also need to make sure you already assigned a license like Ms E5 license to the account so that it has the ability to send the email. I know we could use gmail account to send email, but graph api doesn't have the ability to contact gmail server to send email. Summary: we need to use the account in your tenant which is already assigned a correct license to use this api to send email. Pls correct me if I misunderstood your mean.

Comment: Tiny, I understood your answer . Thanks this was saved my time.

Answer (score 18):

Please note that since Graph API v. 5.0 (march 2023), Microsoft introduced an annoying breaking change, not really well documented (besides obscurely [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/microsoft365dev/write-simpler-code-with-the-new-microsoft-graph-net-sdk-v5/)).

Now, **SendMail** cannot be used anymore as a method of a User. You will get a CS1955 *Non-invocable member cannot be used like a method* compiler error if you try to do that.

You will have to do something like this:

```
        // Your old Message object definition
        Microsoft.Graph.Models.Message msg = new()
        {
            From = ...,
            ToRecipients = ...,
            Subject = "...",

            Body = new ItemBody
            {
                ContentType = BodyType.Html,
                Content = "..."
            }
        };

        Microsoft.Graph.Users.Item.SendMail.SendMailPostRequestBody body = new()
        {
            Message = msg,
            SaveToSentItems = false  // or true, as you want
        };

        try
        {
            await graphClient.Users["your user GUID"]
            .SendMail
            .PostAsync(body);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // log your exception here
        }
```

Comment: WTF............

Comment: Thank you the only answer that worked, again breaking changes "Graph API v. 5.0 (march 2023), Microsoft introduced an annoying breaking change"

await graphClient.Users["your user GUID"]
            .SendMail
            .PostAsync(body);

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can send mail from other user this way.

```
var message = new Message
{
    Subject = "Subject",
    Body = new ItemBody
    {
        ContentType = BodyType.Text,
        Content = "Content"
    },
    ToRecipients = new List<Recipient>()
    {
        new Recipient
        {
            EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
            {
                Address = "john.doe@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
            }
        }
    }
};

var saveToSentItems = false;

await graphClient.Users["userId"]
    .SendMail(message,saveToSentItems)
    .Request()
    .PostAsync();
```

`userId` is the unique identifier for the user. Instead of `userId` you can use `userPrincipalName`. The UPN is an Internet-style login name for the user based on the Internet standard RFC 822. By convention, this should map to the user's email name.

Resources:

[Send mail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp)

[User resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties)

Comment: What is that userId would be?  await graphClient.Users["userId"]

Comment: @Salma userId is a unique identifier of the user. As an alternative you can use user mail instead of user id. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Hi , actually I am looking for  if signed in user is sending email on the name of someone else. Then whose userId would go there.  The intention is the signed in user will not send email from his email address, the email notification will be asthmatically sent by someone else name to someone.  Or I need to get the userid and hardcode it which maybe not right.