# How to send email using Graph API from any or multiple office365 or outlook acccounts?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, office365, mailkit

I was able to send emails using Mailkit SMTP client from multiple accounts. But Microsoft disabled SmtpClientAuthentication for the Tenant.

I checked [Send email using Graph API from service account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71736036/send-email-using-graph-api-from-service-account) link but not working for my me and getting below exception.

Exception message: "One or more errors occurred. (Code: ErrorAccessDenied
Message: Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.
ClientRequestId: 36987ffc-de89-43b1-b3d4-2bc753e54a65
)"

Comment: You followed the documentation how to setup the account/tenant? Especially the [permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#permissions) part when getting "Access is denied"

Comment: Yes, I already added "Application = Mail.Send" permissions.