# I want to send email using graph as any user

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I want to send email using graph as any user.

How do I create an application in azure and what are the permission needed to be given ?

How do I add a user and how do I give admin authority to the user ?

Comment: I think this answer may help you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/70780395/15581227

Comment: `send email using graph as any user` what does it mean? Does it mean you want users sign in first and send email on behalf of himself?

Answer (score 1):

**To create an Azure Ad Application, please follow below steps:**

*Go to Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> App Registrations -> New Registration*

[image]

**To create a user,**

*Go to Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> Users -> New User*

[image]

**To send email, user must have `mail.send` permission. Make sure to assign it like below:**

*Go to Azure Active Directory -> App Registrations -> Your Application -> API permission -> `mail.send`*

[image]

> **how do I give admin authority to the user**

If you want to assign admin role to the user,

*Go to Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> Users -> Select User -> Assigned Roles -> Add assignment -> Select the required role*

[image]

**To send mail, you can make use of below sample code:**

```cs
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );
var message = new Message
{
    Subject = "YourSubject",
    Body = new ItemBody
    {
        ContentType = BodyType.Text,
        Content = "YourContent."
    },
    ToRecipients = new List<Recipient>()
    {
        new Recipient
        {
            EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
            {
                Address = "EmailAddress"
            }
        }
    },
    CcRecipients = new List<Recipient>()
    {
        new Recipient
        {
            EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
            {
                Address = "EmailAddress"
            }
        }
    }
};
var saveToSentItems = false;
await graphClient.Me
    .SendMail(message,saveToSentItems)
    .Request()
    .PostAsync();
```

**References:**

[Send mail - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#request)

[asp.net core - How to send email from any one email using Microsoft Graph by Tiny Wang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70771954/how-to-send-email-from-any-one-email-using-microsoft-graph/70780395#70780395)